# UK visa - bank statements in foreign language

Tags: visas, uk

I'm Ukrainian living and working in Germany and I want to apply for UK visitor visa to go to London for a week with my friend. All my bank statements are in German, although one can surely recognize my name, my account number, name of the bank, dates and how much money I get and spend. Do I have to translate these statements in English?

Comment: To be clear *you* shouldn't be translating any of the statements. You need to pay someone who is recognised by the Home Office to translate the documents. Hopefully you already know this!

Comment: I am sure the Home Office guy doesn't have time to pore over every time you paid the parking meter with your debit card - but that they are interested in seeing that you have a regular source of income. As such I would be surprised if they spent more than 15 seconds looking at your bank statement for a visitor visa. But what do I know... if they can find an excuse to turn you down, they probably will (I wonder if they have quotas).

Answer (score 4):

> If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by 
>   a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office.

[Visit visa: guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf)

Comment: I've also read this quide document, but I'm wondering if I should translate each transaction (I have really a huge number of transactions cause I used to pay everywhere with the card) or it would be enough to translate just keywords like "account balance" or "amount".

Comment: Lots of transactions means all that much more need to get them translated.  Bank statements are not the place to cut corners.

Comment: @Daryna "independently verified by the Home Office." It means a translator needs to do the job for you, I am pretty sure a professional translator knows which parts are required unless it's his first attempt to translate something for the Home Office

Comment: @Daryna My mother in law was refused a UK visa a few months ago.  Her application had many problems, some of which were probably more serious.  But among the reasons given for the refusal was that she had submitted a foreign-language bank statement without a translation.